# Extending a line between 2 points in 3D space

Tags: c, 3d, geometry, line, points

Let's say I have 2 points in 3D space, one at:

```
x=2, y=3, z=5
```

and the second one at:

```
x=6, y=7, z=10
```

What is the fastest way, in code, to calculate the coordinates of a *third* point from extending (for example, doubling) the distance between those two points (relative to point one)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Maybe you want one of the Maths based stack exchanges?

Comment: I needed this for a program I am writing so I thought writing it here would be okay. I also didn't know that there was a Maths based stack exchange. Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a point extended as far beyond `(x2,y2,z2)` as that is beyond `(x1,y1,z1)`:

```
x3 = x2 + (x2 - x1) (= 10)
y3 = y2 + (y2 - y1) (= 11)
z3 = z2 + (z2 - z1) (= 15)
```

or:

```
(x2 * 2 - x1, y2 * 2 -y1, z2 * 2 - z1)
```

Simple as that.

If you want something other than double the length, you can scale the `(x2 - x1)`-type terms. For example, if you want it 50% longer than the current line, multiply them by `0.5` (+50%). If you want it three times longer, multiply them by two (+200%).

In terms of *code* that can perform this extension, something like this, which gives you an endpoint `pDest` that, along with, `p1` forms a line `percent` times the size of `p1-p2`:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} tPoint3d;

void extend (tPoint3d *p1, tPoint3d *p2, double percent, tPoint3d *pDest) {
    percent -= 100.0;                             // what to ADD
    percent /= 100.0;                             // make multiplier
    pDest->x = p2->x + percent * (p2->x - p1->x); // scale each point
    pDest->y = p2->y + percent * (p2->y - p1->y);
    pDest->z = p2->z + percent * (p2->z - p1->z);
}
```

Comment: beautiful yet simple answer +1